# Solve the limit $\lim_{x\to2}({\frac{1}{x(x-2)^2}-\frac{1}{x^2-3x+2})}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to2}\left(\frac{1}{x(x-2)^2}-\frac{1}{x^2-3x+2}\right)$$

**What I tried:** Got the fraction to the same denominator
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to2}{\frac{x^2-3x+2-x(x-2)^2}{x(x-2)^2(x^2-3x+2)}}&=\lim_{x\to2}{\frac{(x-2)(x-1)-x(x-2)^2}{x(x-2)^2(x-2)(x-1)}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to2}{\frac{x-1-x^2+2x}{x(x-2)^2(x-1)}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to2}{\frac{x-1-x^2+2x}{x(x-2)^2(x-1)}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to2}{\frac{x-1-x^2+2x}{x(x-2)^2(x-1)}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to2}{\frac{-x^2+3x-1}{x(x-2)^2(x-1)}}\\
&={\frac{-4+6-1}{0}}
\end{align}$$

There is a mistake that I can't find...

Answer (score 3):

The numerator tend to a positive number, the denominator goes to $0$ from the positive directione. The sequence actually goes to infinity.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use that $$x^2-3x+2-x(x-2)^2=-(x-2)(x^2-3x+1)$$ and $$x^2-3x+2=(x-1)(x-2)$$

Answer (score 1):

By $y=x-2 \to 0$ we have that

$$\lim_{x\to 2} \left({\frac{1}{x(x-2)^2}-\frac{1}{x^2-3x+2}}\right)=\lim_{y\to 0} \left({\frac{1}{y^2(y+2)}-\frac{1}{y(y+1)}}\right)$$

and

$${\frac{1}{y^2(y+2)}-\frac{1}{y(y+1)}}={\frac{y+1-y^2-2y}{y^2(y+1)(y+2)}}=\frac1y\cdot{\frac{-y^2-y+1}{(y+1)(y+2)}}\to \infty$$

Comment: @user376343 mmmmhhhhh yes I thing there is something wrong with that! I fix...thanks